# .net facebook get public posts by keywords

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am new to the facebook graph api and i am trying to write a c# program that searches facebook 
for specific keywords, therefore i use the .net Facebook SDK.

```
        Facebook.FacebookClient fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient();
        dynamic x = fb.Get("search?q=keyword&type=post");
```

When i execute the query i get an oauth error.
Here is my question, must i create a facebook app to get access to the public posts via the open graph api, or do i not need such an app, if yes, why do i need it?

Kind Regards
Manues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need to create a Facebook app to use the Search feature even if it is just public posts.  As far as I know, this is just required by Facebook for privacy and/or tracking reasons.

For more information see here: [Facebook API - Search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/)

For searching all public posts by keyword, you can use an app access_token.  To get this, create a Facebook APP, and use the App ID and App Secret to generate the access_token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={APP_ID}&client_secret={APP_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials
```